# Get object with min() column value in a 2d object array

Tags: php, arrays, object, multidimensional-array, min

I'm trying to retrieve the object which has the lowest distance value from an array of objects. This is my data set below;

```
[0] => myObjectThing Object
    (
        [name:myObjectThing:private] => asadasd
        [distance:myObjectThinge:private] => 0.9826368952306
    )

[1] => myObjectThing Object
    (
        [name:myObjectThing:private] => 214gerwert24
        [distance:myObjectThinge:private] => 1.5212312547306
    )

[2] => myObjectThing Object
    (
        [name:myObjectThing:private] => abc123
        [distance:myObjectThinge:private] => 0.0000368952306
    )
```

So I'd like to be able to retieve the object which has the smallest distance value. In this case it would be object with name: `abc123`

** EDIT ** What would happen if I only used arrays, e.g.

```
array(
      array('name' => 'bla', 'distance' => '123');
      array('name' => 'b123a', 'distance' => '1234214');
);
```

Would this be easier to find the min value?

Comment: "What would happen if I only used arrays?" - you could then array_multisort (http://au2.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php). But it wouldn't make a bug difference in this case because you can just use array_walk

Comment: Typically the fringe clarification that is asked is: What is the preferred output if two of the objects have the same minimal `distance` value?  The answers below are only returning the first encountered min.  On other pages on Stack Overflow, an array of results is populated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hmm for PHP >= 5.3 I would try something like this:

```
$Object = array_reduce($data,function($A,$B){
    return $A->distance < $B->distance ? $A : $B;
})
```

For PHP < 5.3 the fillowing would suffice:

```
function user_defined_reduce($A,$B){
    return $A->distance < $B->distance ? $A : $B;
}
$Object = array_reduce($data,"user_defined_reduce");
```

Answer (score 7):

Previously suggested answers did not explain the need to include an `$initial` value to `array_reduce()`. The solution did not work because of it.

This one works for me (PHP 5.3.13):

```
$array = array(
    array(
        'name' => 'something',
        'value' => 56
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'else',
        'value' => 54
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'else',
        'value' => 58
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'else',
        'value' => 78
    )
);
$object = array_reduce($array, function($a, $b){
    return $a['value'] < $b['value'] ? $a : $b;
}, array_shift($array));

print_r($object);
```

This will give me:

```
[0] => Array
(
    [name] => else
    [value] => 54
)
```

Whereas the previous solution gave me `null`. I'm assuming that PHP < 5.3 would require a similar initial value to be specified to `array_reduce()`.

Comment: If you're looking for a minimum value with array_reduce in unsorted array, I think there's a chance you won't get the minimum value?

Answer (score 0):

You can't flatten this as it isn't a plain old multi-dimensional array with just the values.

This should work:

```
$min = $object[0];
for ($i = 1; $i < count($object); $i++)
    if ($object[$i]['distance'] < $min['distance'])
        $min = $object[$i];
```

Comment: And which object has the minimal value ? You didn't got it - just minimal value.

Comment: If I didn't use objects and just had a massive array would this be easier? Only problem with doing it with a big array is that it's a bit hacky. My only problem with using another loop is that I am already at O(n^2) which will be huge if i wrap another loop in there

Comment: Would it be possible to integrate it into your main loop to avoid pushing past O(n)? Or is your main loop not through the objects?

Comment: It's through another data set, so i'm pulling data then for each element im then making another request for that data. If i added another loop within this i think it would be too cumbersome

Answer (score 0):

```
$objectsArray = array(...); // your objects
$distance     = null;
$matchedObj   = null;

foreach ( $objectsArray as $obj ) {
   if ( is_null($distance) || ( $obj->distance < $distance ) ) {
      $distance   = $obj->distance;
      $matchedObj = $obj;
   }
}

var_dump($matchedObj);
```

`AD EDIT:`

If you will use arrays instead of objects, change `$obj->distance` to `$obj['distance']`.

Answer (score 0):

This example should give you a hint in the right direction:

```
<?php

$a = new stdClass();
$a->foo = 2;
$b = new stdClass();
$b->foo = 3;
$c = new stdClass();
$c->foo = 1;

$init = new stdClass();
$init->foo = 1000;

$vals = array( $a, $b, $c );

var_dump(
    array_reduce(
        $vals,
        function ( $x, $y )
        {
            if ( $x->foo < $y->foo )
            {
                return $x;
            }   
            else
            {
                return $y;
            }   
        },  
        $init
    )   
);  

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$myObjectCollection = ...;
$minObject = $myObjectCollection[0]; // or reset($myObjectCollection) if you can't ensure  numeric 0 index

array_walk($myObjectCollection, function($object) use ($minObject) { 
        $minObject = $object->distance < $minObject->distance ? $object : $minObject;
});
```

but from the looks of your dump. `name` and `distance` are private. So you want be able to access them from the object directly using `->`. You'll need some kind of getter `getDistance()`

Answer (score -1):

I stumbled on this question while I was searching for a way to find the lowest value instead of the entire object. In case somebody else is looking for the same thing, here's my approach:

```
$min_value = min( array_map( fn($o) => $o->my_prop, $objects ) );
```

Comment: Differently from other answers, this concise snippet will iterate over the array twice instead of only once.  This answer does not return the "minimal object", it returns the minimal `my_prop` value.